# Call a JavaScript function in a Google Chrome window from a vb.net program

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-chrome

I am having a real problem with this.

I want to know if it is possible to run/call a javascript function in a Google Chrome web browser window from a VB.net application.

The scenario is that i want to monitor the pc activity (which i know how to) and then if a certain event is met (for example, high ram usage) then it calls a JavaScript function in a Google Chrome web browser window so the website is updated. Sort of like a bridge.

The only bit it need to know is the vb.net code for how to access a chrome window and invoke a javascript function if its possible. I assume i will need to use process handlers?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Need to clarify, the VB.net is desktop not web (Win forms)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using web sockets. [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) is a decent enough library to look at, [here's](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections) a nice example to get you started.

Comment: Hi thanks but this would appear to only work for asp.net server to web? I need to bridge the gap from desktop program to web browser